# Android Studio Build APK ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

My app is split in many projects, which are included as a dependency in my main library which is a dependency in my app.

- Project Main

  - Module App

    - Dependencies

      - MainLibrary Module
  - Module MainLibrary

    - Dependencies

      - Project X
      - Project Y
- Project X

  - Module 1
  - Module 2
- Project Y

  - Module 1

My first problem is, that my dependency to Project X is not packaged in my APK Dex File and i get a ClassNotFoundException if the app starts and the class in this module is used.
I declare the dependency with **provided project(':beacon')**

The second problem is, that i have to declare the dependencies in my MainLibrary Module and in my AppModule. Thats twice.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the `provided` dependency scope -- it uses the dependency for compiling but doesn't bundle it into the output. Use the `compile` scope instead.

As for needing to declare a dependency on **Project X** in more than one place, that's because dependencies aren't transitive. If **Module App** depends on **Project X**, it needs to declare that explicitly and not depend on getting it through a sub-dependency. That's not to say that if you use the `compile` scope the sub-dependency won't be included in the output, but if you want to depend on it from a parent module, it needs to declare its dependency separately.

Comment: Thank you. It works.
My Module App has no Code. There is only the AndroidManifest.xml and the dependencie to the MainLibrary. But i have to declare the dependencies from the MainLibrary in the Module App. Is that correct?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need the module then if it has no code (and presumably no resources, though you didn't say).